# Error When Capturing from the Surface Camera

Tags: android, service, camera, surface

I have an error when starting camera service from location service that I created, the error not show when I start service from Main Activity.

This is when capturing success that shows **"app pass Null Surface"** : Success

[image]

The error is not showing app **"app pass Null Surface"** : Error

[image]

This the code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@BindView(R.id.ButtonUpload) Button btnupload;
@BindView(R.id.ButtonService2) Button btnservice;
@BindView(R.id.ButtonService3) Button btnservice2;
@BindView(R.id.longitude) TextView tvlongitude;
@BindView(R.id.latitude) TextView tvlatitude;
@BindView(R.id.derajat) TextView tvderajat;

private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 101;
private String degree;
boolean boolean_permission;

Double latitude,longitude;
Geocoder geocoder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    btnupload.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnservice.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnservice2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.ButtonUpload:

            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraService.class));

            break;

        case R.id.ButtonService2:

            if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Location.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Berjalan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startService(intent);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.ButtonService3:

            Intent location = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Location.class);
            stopService(location);

            break;
    }

}
```

Camera Service:

```
public class CameraService extends HiddenCameraService {
Bitmap bitmap;
String encodedImage;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (HiddenCameraUtils.canOverDrawOtherApps(this)) {
            CameraConfig cameraConfig = new CameraConfig()
                    .getBuilder(this)
                    .setCameraFacing(CameraFacing.REAR_FACING_CAMERA)
                    .setCameraResolution(CameraResolution.MEDIUM_RESOLUTION)
                    .setImageFormat(CameraImageFormat.FORMAT_JPEG)
                    .setCameraFocus(CameraFocus.AUTO)
                    .build();

            startCamera(cameraConfig);

            new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Camera","Capturing Camera");
                    takePicture();
                }
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            //Open settings to grant permission for "Draw other apps".
            HiddenCameraUtils.openDrawOverPermissionSetting(this);
        }
    } else {

        //TODO Ask your parent activity for providing runtime permission
        Log.e("Camera", "Permission Not Available");
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onImageCapture(@NonNull File imageFile) {

    Uri filepath = getImageContentUri(getApplicationContext(),imageFile);

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(filepath));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlUpload, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Succes : " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            String imageData = imageToString(bitmap);
            params.put("image",imageData);

            return params;

        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    stopSelf();
}

private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, outputStream);
    byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
    String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { filePath }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        cursor.close();
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraError(@CameraError.CameraErrorCodes int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case CameraError.ERROR_CAMERA_OPEN_FAILED:
            //Camera open failed. Probably because another application
            //is using the camera
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error cannot open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case CameraError.ERROR_IMAGE_WRITE_FAILED:
            //Image write failed. Please check if you have provided WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error cannot write", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case CameraError.ERROR_CAMERA_PERMISSION_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            //camera permission is not available
            //Ask for the camera permission before initializing it.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error cannot get Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case CameraError.ERROR_DOES_NOT_HAVE_OVERDRAW_PERMISSION:
            //Display information dialog to the user with steps to grant "Draw over other app"
            //permission for the app.
            HiddenCameraUtils.openDrawOverPermissionSetting(this);
            break;
        case CameraError.ERROR_DOES_NOT_HAVE_FRONT_CAMERA:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error no camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }

    stopSelf();
}
}
```

Location Service that i want call Camera Service:

```
public class Location extends Service implements LocationListener, SensorEventListener {

boolean isGPSEnable = false;
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
double latitude, longitude;
LocationManager locationManager;
android.location.Location location;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;
long notify_interval = 10 * 1000;
public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
Intent intent;
private float currentDegree = 0f;

// device sensor manager
private SensorManager mSensorManager;

public Location() {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5, notify_interval);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    fn_getlocation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

private void fn_getlocation() {
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(isNetworkEnable) {
        location = null;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, notify_interval, 0, this);
            if (locationManager!=null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location!=null){

                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

                    fn_update(location);

                    if(latitude<-5 & longitude<128) {
                        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CameraService.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (isGPSEnable){
        location = null;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, notify_interval, 0, this);
            if (locationManager!=null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location!=null){

                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

                    fn_update(location);

                    if(latitude<-5 & longitude<128) {
                        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CameraService.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```